# how to start browser in j2me app without confirmation

Tags: java, java-me, midp, verisign

I'm developing first j2me app which should just open a browser with some url. I do it with only one line of code

```
platformRequest(URL);
```

When I run it - it always asks me "Do I really want to open such URL"

How can I solve it? Will the app signing on the verisign solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Singing is the only option to access such APIs. You must sing your mobile application with a Singing Authority Certificate like [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/) ,[Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Even after Signing with Authority Tools , we cannot skip those prompts in all J2ME devices.
But after Signing we will get extra prompts like "Access For ALL" .